# S3 download object using pre signed v4 signautre

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any example in C# to see how to pre-sign all objects using a start-with policy with [AWS v4 signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) to let customers download object from their respective folder structure instead signing each document separately.

The documentation says :

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/examplebucket/test.txt
?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Credential=<your-access-key-id>/20130721/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
&X-Amz-Date=20130721T201207Z
&X-Amz-Expires=86400
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Signature=<signature-value>
```

But my signature is not working for GET (download) object, **while working correctly  for upload**

```
void Main()
{
    string bucket = "bucket-name-here";
    string s3Key = "s3-key-here";
    string s3Secret = "secret-here";
    string s3Region = "us-east-1";
    string Date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    string xAmzDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "T000000Z";
    string expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");

    string policyString = $@"{{""expiration"":""{expiration}"",""conditions"":[{{""bucket"":""{bucket}""}},{{""acl"":""private""}},[""starts-with"",""$key"",""Client_1""],[""starts-with"",""$Content-Type"",""""],[""starts-with"",""$filename"",""""],{{""x-amz-date"":""{xAmzDate}""}},{{""x-amz-credential"":""{s3Key}/{Date}/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request""}},{{""x-amz-algorithm"":""AWS4-HMAC-SHA256""}}]}}";

    var policyStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(policyString);
    var policy = Convert.ToBase64String(policyStringBytes);
    //policy.Dump();


    byte[] signingKey = GetSigningKey(s3Secret, Date, s3Region, "s3");
    byte[] signature = HmacSHA256(policy, signingKey);

    var sign = ToHexString(signature);

    sign.Dump();
}

static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key)
{
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
    kha.Key = key;

    return kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}

private byte[] GetSigningKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName)
{
    byte[] kSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(("AWS4" + key).ToCharArray());
    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
    return kSigning;
}

public static string ToHexString(byte[] data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(data[i].ToString("x2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

More about the problem: We have thousands of documents for hundreds of clients on S3 on their respective folder structure as below. Right now, every time the client is looking to download their object they gets signed by our API to created the downloadable link > so each document is signed separately.

**Client 1**

```
Client_1/Document1.xyz 
Client_1/Document2.xyz
```

**Client 2**

```
Client_2/Document1.xyz 
Client_2/Document2.xyz
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, please note that you have a security vulnerability in your upload policy. `[""starts-with"",""$key"",""Client_1""]` should be `[""starts-with"",""$key"",""Client_1/""]`, otherwise Client_1 can overwrite the files of Client_10, Client_11, etc., for any client whose identifier is a left-anchored substring of another client, because you didn't put a terminating delimiter in your policy statement's constraint on the object key.  This policy is visible in the browser, so a malicious user could easily find and exploit this.

Comment: Thanks very much @Michael-sqlbot for this. I accept your vulnerability, while it's not visible on browser and the browser see the hashed policy + signature by our API and those hashed values is used in s3 request headers for put request..Note the Convert.ToBase64String(policyStringBytes) in my code. But anyway great catch and really appreciated. Any suggestion on actual question as well?

Comment: For all practical purposes, the policy contents are still "visible" even if not literally visible to the eyeball, because base64 is not a hashing algorithm. It is trivial to decode.

Answer (score 0):

The signing algorithm for S3 HTML form `POST` uploads allows you to sign a policy document with constraints like `["starts-with","$key",...]` but pre-signed URLs for S3 don't support this.  With a pre-signed URL, you sign not a policy document but a "canonical request," which is a canonicalized representation of the browser's *exact* request.  So there is no support for wildcards or prefixes.

There are two alternatives that come to mind.

[CloudFront signed URLs and signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) do support a policy document when you use a "custom policy" (not a "canned policy," which is more like what S3 supports) and a custom policy allows a `*` in the URL, similar to `["starts-with","$key",...]` but using the URL the browser will be requesting.  You only have to do the signing once, and the code running in the browser can reuse that policy and signature.  On the back-side of CloudFront, a CloudFront Origin Access Identity is used to sign the requests as they are actually sent to the bucket, after authenticating the request on the front-side of CloudFront using the CloudFront signed URL or signed cookies.  (With signed cookies, the browser just makes the request, and automatically submits the cookies, so that works the same but with no browser manipulation of the URLs.

Alternately, the [`AssumeRole`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) action in Security Token Service could be called by your server, to generate a set of temporary credentials for the client to use, to sign its own individual URLs.

When calling `AssumeRole`, you can also pass an optional *session policy* document.  If you do, then the generated temporary credentials can only perform actions allowed by both the role policy ("allow read from the bucket") and the session policy ("allow read from the bucket for keys beginning with a specific prefix").  So the role credentials obtained would only allow the user to access to their objects.

Comment: AssumeRole seems to be my choice as cloudfront will add additional cost. Before I try that, is there any other way like adding a different header {token : xyz} on each documents and then give that token to customers? because the solution I am looking is for GET objects only as the above approach is working fine for PUT.

Comment: I can think of no suitable "different header" solution with native support.  Do note that the cost of using CloudFront is typically negligible, and can even result in a net savings depending on the size of the objects and the locations of the viewer and bucket.  In us-east-2, for example, S3 download bandwidth is $0.090/GB but CloudFront download bandwidth for a viewer in the U.S. is $0.085/GB.  Bandwidth from S3 to CloudFront is free, so you don't pay double, you pay slightly less.

Comment: Thanks, I will try both ways to see what works better for our use case. Keeping the answer un-accepted for a week to see if any other suggestion from community.

Comment: That's perfectly fair and reasonable.  Let's see if any other suggestions come up.

Comment: Of course, there *are* other alternatives that occurred to me, but I didn't include them since they were more "creative" and outside the box.  For example, using Lambda@Edge to authenticate the user based on a session cookie (maybe a little bit like your `token: xyz` but not static).  I have a "side-car" application that does this, and it's straightforward *in my case* because the sessions are stored by the main app in DynamoDB -- so Lambda@Edge can look up the session data by cookie and determine permissions independently, without imposing any load on the conventional application servers.